# Can the maximum image size of picard library be adjusted?

Tags: asp.net, image, image-uploading

I use the `piczard` library to resize some images once I upload them.

The code is only a few lines:

```
Dim resizeFilter As ScaledResizeConstraint = New ScaledResizeConstraint(1000, 800)
    resizeFilter.EnlargeSmallImages = False
    resizeFilter.SaveProcessedImageToFileSystem(originalLocation, photo.GetPhotoPath(photoId), New JpegFormatEncoderParams(85))
```

However, I get the following error in my logs when i upload a panoramic photo:

```
CodeCarvings.Piczard.InvalidImageSizeExceptionPiczard error: Invalid image size {Width=11248, Height=1600}. The maximum image size is: {Width=7000, Height=7000}.
```

Is there a way to set the maximum size that the `piczard` library will accept before manipulating an image?

Comment: Have you tried the `maxImageSize` attribute of the `drawing` node available in the [piczard config settings](http://piczard.com/docs/help/v1/online/?Core_Settings.html)?

Comment: That was the answer, Thanks! Not sure i can accept your comment as the answer.

Comment: Mike J, no problem. Happy to help. I've added an actual answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `maxImageSize` config setting as described in the Piczard [documentation](http://piczard.com/docs/help/v1/online/?InvalidImageSizeException.html):

> By default, if you try to load or process an image whose size is
>   greater than 5000 (width) x 5000 (height) pixels, Piczard raises an
>   InvalidImageSizeException.
>
> You can change this limit by editing the application Config file. In
>   particular you have to add / edit the value of following attribute:
>
> configuration / codeCarvings.piczard / coreSettings / drawing /
>   maxImageSize

**Example config file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
     <sectionGroup name="codeCarvings.piczard">
        <section name="coreSettings" type="CodeCarvings.Piczard.Configuration.CoreSettingsSectionHandler, CodeCarvings.Piczard" requirePermission="false"/>
     </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <codeCarvings.piczard>
     <coreSettings>
        <drawing maxImageSize="10000, 8000" />
        <imageArchiver defaultLoadImageValidateImageData="false" />
     </coreSettings>
  </codeCarvings.piczard>
</configuration>
```